# ArcGIS arcpy code fails in Toolbox mode

Tags: arcpy, error-000732

This code executes correctly in Python window but fails with

> ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset JHJ does not exist or is not supported

```
# Import ArcPy and other required modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import fileinput
import string
import os
env.overwriteOutput = True
filud=file(r"c:\temp\dum.txt","w")     # Open file for debug output
filud.write("Hello \n")
try:
   # Will create shape file fcname.shp
   arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(r"C:\temp\TestArcGis\FraFil","JHJ","Polyline")
   filud.write(str(time.time()) + " After create \n")
except Exception as e:
   filud.write(str(time.time()) + "Error: " + e.message + "\n")
try:
   # Add fields for data
   filud.write(str(time.time()) + " Before Addfield " + "JHJ" + "\n")
   arcpy.AddField_management("JHJ","Sbet","TEXT")
except Exception as e:
  print e.message
  filud.write("Error: " + e.message)
filud.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

It works in the python window because JHJ is likely a layer in the map and therefore can be reference in your script as "JHJ". When run outside of Arcmap, you need to tell arcpy where to look. Here are just a few ways you can do this (untested, but it should give you a few ideas):

1)

```
jhj = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(r"C:\temp\TestArcGis\FraFil","JHJ","Polyline")
......
arcpy.AddField_management(jhj,"Sbet","TEXT")
```

2)

```
env.workspace=r"C:\temp\TestArcGis\FraFil"
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(r"C:\temp\TestArcGis\FraFil","JHJ","Polyline")
......
arcpy.AddField_management("JHJ","Sbet","TEXT")
```

3)

```
jhj = r"C:\temp\TestArcGis\FraFil\JHJ"
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(*os.path.split(jhj),"Polyline")
......
arcpy.AddField_management(jhj,"Sbet","TEXT")
```

Answer (score 1):

In AddField, provide the full path to JHJ or change your workspace (arcpy.env.workspace) to r"C:\temp\TestArcGis\FraFil" before AddField.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting arcpy.env.workspace to your working directory.  e.g.,

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = 'c:/temp/testarcgis/frafil'
```